# Finding the dimension of a multivariable polynomial quotient ring

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

> Determine the cardinality of the set $ V (x^3-yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y ) $ and compare this to the dimension of $ \dfrac{ \mathbb C [x,y,z]}{\langle x^3-yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y \rangle} $ viewed as a complex vector space.

For the first part, I obtained a parametric family of solutions $ (x,y,z) = (t^3, t^4, t^5), \; t \in \mathbb C $ so the vanishing set is infinite. I believe the answer to the second part is infinite but I'm not sure how to verify this in the given case (so far, I've only encountered the quotient of a polynomial ring in a single variable)

Comment: In the quotient ring, it should be $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ not $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, right?

Comment: @JaneDoé Apologies, you're completely right and I'll fix that now

Comment: My rough idea: the quotient ring is the "algebraic version" of $V(\cdots)$, and since you found an isomorphism $V(\cdots) \cong \mathbb{A}^1$, there should be a corresponding isomorphism with $k[t]$ on the level of functions. Namely, we can define a map $\phi : \mathbb{C}[x,y,z] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t]$ that sends $x \mapsto t^3,\, y \mapsto t^4,\, z \mapsto t^5$. Then, argue that $\phi$ factors through the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z] / \langle x^3 \cdots x^2y \rangle$ and  that the induced map is an isom. It is then easy to find the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ as $\mathbb{C}$-v.sp.

Comment: @JaneDoé Sorry, I'm not sure what exactly you mean by factoring through and the induced map. I understan that if the given ring contains $ \mathbb C [t] $ then it's dimension must be infinite, but the mapping you wrote doesn't produce say $ t^2 $ so it's not necessarily an isomorphism?

Comment: Sorry, you're right --- I had the solution of a similar problem in mind and did not think carefully enough about this one. The image of $\phi$ is certainly a subring of $k[t]$, so it will not be an isomorphism with $\mathbb{C}[t]$ (though it may still be an isomorphism with its image, I need to think a bit more about that). By "induced map" I just mean there is a well-defined map from the quotient to $\mathbb{C}[t]$ that sends $x \mapsto t^3,\, y \mapsto t^4,\, z \mapsto t^5$ (this should be true because points of the form $(t^3,t^4,t^5)$ satisfy the defining equations of the variety).

Comment: So I'm pretty confident that $\ker(\phi) = \langle x^3-yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y \rangle$, so $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/\langle x^3-yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y \rangle \cong \mathbb{C}[t^3,t^4,t^5] = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}t^3 \oplus \mathbb{C}t^4\oplus \mathbb{C}t^5\oplus \mathbb{C}t^6\oplus \mathbb{C}t^7\oplus \cdots $. This is an interesting example because the curve given by the vanishing of the 3 polynomials is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, but not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ as a variety (because they have different rings of functions)!

Comment: @JaneDoé How did you get the equality on the kernel? I think your approach is fine but all you need is that $ \langle x^3 - yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y \rangle \subset \; \text{ker} \phi \implies \dfrac{\mathbb C [t]}{ \langle x^3 - yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y \rangle } \supset \dfrac{\mathbb C [t]}{\text{ker} \phi} \cong \mathbb C [t^3, t^4, t^5] $, which means be must be infinite as it contains an infinite dimensional subspace. Showing that the kernel only consists of such elements seems like a much harder task to me and I can't see any way of doing it off the top of my head

Comment: Well... suppose that $0 = \phi(f(x,y,z)) = f(t^3,t^4,t^5)$. Then $f$ vanishes on all points of $X = V(x^3-yz, y^2-xz, z^2-x^2y)$, hence $f$ is contained in the ideal of $X$. LOL! Nice and circular... But I agree, showing the other inclusion without cheating is a difficult problem.